# Giving out wrong value when evaluating COUNTIF function using apache poi formula evaluation

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have one excel workbook file in which there are 2 sheets. Sheet 1 has two columns which are just like values and criteria's like
[image]

and the other sheet has formula defined as `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A13,Sheet1!B2:B4)`

so other sheet looks like
[image]

Now when I am reading this second sheet, I want to evaluate the formula to extract the correct values from the workbook but it is giving all wrong values.
Code is as follows:

```
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

Iterator<Row> rowIterator = workbook.getSheetAt(1).iterator();
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
            String cellFormula = cell.getCellFormula();
            System.out.println("Cell Formula=" + cellFormula);
            CellType cellType = evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
            if (cellType == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            }

        } else if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC)
            System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    }
}
closeFIS();
```

Could some one please point me what wrong I am doing here...

Answer (score 3):

Used as normal worksheet function, [COUNTIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) does not use a cell range as second parameter but only one value or one cell reference.

If you have `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A13,Sheet1!B2:B4)` as formula in a sheet, then you are using that function as [dynamic array formula using spilled array behavior](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531). Current Excel versions provide this. But Apache POI (current versions of January 2023) cannot evaluate such formulas properly.

If you would have normal worksheet functions in your Sheet2, such as:

`=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A13,Sheet1!B2)` in `Sheet2!A1`

`=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A13,Sheet1!B3)` in `Sheet2!A2`

`=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A13,Sheet1!B4)` in `Sheet2!A3`

then formula evaluation should work.

Comment: Yes that is what I tested and it worked. Thanks.

Any other java library which can help doing this?